# how to use meta tag to redirect user

Tags: php

I am trying to get my view count to work in my forum and am thinking that I might need a unique column, so decided to give a tinyint and set a default to 1. If the user submits a new topic, it should say 1 and a reply should set it to 0 but for some reason, when I replied to my topic, it will set both back to 0 as shown below in my database:

[image: tinyint default 1]

This is the code for both my topic and reply section.... from my understanding, if I set the tinyint default to 1, I don't have to include it in my insert statement correct?

```
<? php
include_once 'header2.php';
if (!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
  header("Location: index.php?create_music_topic_process=notlogin");
  exit();
} else {

  include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
  $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
  $cat = $_POST['cat'];
  $admin = $_POST['admin'];
  $topic_title = $_POST['topic_title'];
  $topic_description = $_POST['topic_description'];
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  if (strlen($topic_title) < 1 || strlen($topic_title) > 64) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=display_music_forum_topics.php?cat=".$cat.
    "&topic_id=".$topic_id.
    "&create_music_topic_process=wronglength'>";
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO music_forum_topics (cat_id, topic_id, user_uid, topic_title, topic_description, date_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iissss", $cat, $topic_id, $_SESSION['u_uid'], $topic_title, $topic_description, $date);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM music_forum_topics WHERE cat_id = ? AND topic_id = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $cat, $topic_id);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
      $id = $row2['id'];
    }

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=display_music_forum.php?create_music_topic=success'>";

  }


}
```

This is my reply code:

```
<? php
include_once 'header2.php';
if (!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
  header("Location: index.php?create_music_topics_process=notlogin");
  exit();
} else {
  if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("Location: create_music_topics_reply.php?create_music_topics_process=error");
    exit();
  } else {
    $reply = $_POST['reply'];
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
    $topic_title = $_POST['topic_title'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $creator = $_POST['creator'];
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    $topic_reply = $row2['topic_reply'];
    $topic_reply += 1;
    $unique_id = $_POST['unique_id'];
    $original_thread = 0;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO music_forum_topics (cat_id, topic_id, original_thread, user_uid, topic_title, topic_description, date_reply) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiissss", $cat, $topic_id, $original_thread, $creator, $topic_title, $reply, $date);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM music_forum_topics WHERE topic_id = ? AND cat_id = ?;";

    $original_thread = 0;

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $topic_id, $cat);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

      $sql3 = "UPDATE music_forum_topics
      SET topic_reply = ?
        WHERE original_thread = ?
        ";

      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
        echo "SQL error";
      } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $resultCheck2, $original_thread);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=display_music_forum.php?create_music_topics_reply_process=success'>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to manually insert the value into db from either tool which you are using to access your db.

If that work then it means that your code has an error else the error exists in your db only.